# Page counter switch roman - arabic - roman (on specific page)

Tags: page-numbering

I am trying to have Roman page numbering for Acknowledgements, Lists etc. - then Switch to arabic page numbering - and then Switch back to Roman for references and Appendix.

This works fine, however, the page where it switches back to Roman can't be defined properly: if I set the command before the `\printbibliography`, the last chapter is also formatted with Roman page numbers. If I set it after the `\printbibliography`, the Bibliography remains in arabic.

How can I fix that? See MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\input{Chapters/Acknowledgements}

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapters/1_intro}

\chapter{Concluding Summary}
\input{Chapters/8_summary}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{8}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does a `\clearpage` before `\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{8}` help?  (Is it really necessary to set the page number explicitly?)

Comment: It does - amazing, thank you! It is necessary because the Count otheriwse starts at (i) again, I want it to be continous.

Comment: See my 'solution' -- By the way, your example isn't compilable -- it misses the `\usepackage{biblatex}` statement

Comment: Thanks for the corrections - I'm still a beginner so happy about any Feedback.

Comment: No worries -- We are prepared to lure users to the Dark Side ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page` numbering problems can be solved in almost any case with a preceeding `\clearpage`.

In addition, `\pagenumbering{...}` always resets the page counter. If the page counting should be done continously, rather use `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\blindtext[4]

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
We all love \cite{Lam94}!

\blindtext[4]

\chapter{Concluding Summary}
%\input{Chapters/8_summary}
\blindtext[6]
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
%\setcounter{page}{8}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jenny If this answer solved your problem and answered your question, please consider upvoting the answer and accepting it using the green checkmark. That is the preferred way of saying *thank you* here (though of course a nice comment with a thank you can't hurt either).